# Get template part in WordPress plugin

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to move a WordPress plugin from my child theme to a custom plugin. The current code is using get_template_part which works on the child theme but not on the custom WordPress plugin.

I have tried to replace it for "include" but it doesn't work.

```
function arbolesplantados_endpoint_content() {
    get_template_part('arbolesplantados'); //I think the problem is here
}

add_action( 'woocommerce_account_arbolesplantados_endpoint', 'arbolesplantados_endpoint_content' );


function arbolesplantados_account_menu_items( $items ) {

    $my_items = array(
         'arbolesplantados' => __( 'Gestionar &aacute;rboles plantados', 'woocommerce' )
    );

    $my_items = array_slice( $items, 0, 1, true ) +
         $my_items +
         array_slice( $items, 1, count( $items ), true );


    return $my_items;

}

add_filter( 'woocommerce_account_menu_items', 'arbolesplantados_account_menu_items');
```

The previous code is supposed to create a page with the woocommerce menu (my account) on the left and then on the right print the custom form that's inside a file called arbolesplantados.php which is in the root folder of my plugin

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You missed to register endpoint for the custom page. You can register endpoint like this.

```
function wpso_add_my_account_endpoint() {
    add_rewrite_endpoint( 'arbolesplantados', EP_PAGES );
}
add_action( 'init', 'wpso_add_my_account_endpoint' );
```